# "connecting to react ...." in react-devtools, when I want to connect with react native android emulator

Tags: react-native, react-devtools

I want to connect to react-devtools. I installed it later.I change:
On android emulator press cmd +m Dev Settings > Debug server host & port for device >"localhost:8097" because react-devtools connect with port=8097.
After all changes, react devtools show 
"connecting to React.....
Click here for troubleshooting instructions" 
this link does'nt work!
what do I should do?
Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching throughout the internet for the same answer you seek. I have checked countless stackoverflow articles, YouTube videos, and GitHub forums, with no luck. However, I did find an alternative tool that includes most of the same functionality AND MORE! :)

It is called "react-native-debugger", and it is available via npm (Node Package Manager) as well.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-debugger
- https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

It seems like this package is tailored specifically to React Native, and it even has some Redux debugging tools built-in too. It has been updated much more frequently than the "react-devtools" package has, with some updates as recent as this week.

I had much better luck with this package, hopefully this helps you!